# SUM up all values of each row and write the results in a new column using Bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a big file (many columns) that generally looks like:

```
Gene,A,B,C
Gnai3,2,3,4
P53,5,6,7
H19,4,4,4
```

I want to sum every row of the data frame and add it as a new column as below:

```
Gene,A,B,C,total
Gnai3,2,3,4,9
P53,5,6,7,18
H19,4,4,4,12
```

I tried `awk -F, '{sum=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; print sum}'` but then I am not able to make a new column for the total counts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new column, just increment number of columns and assign the new column a value:

```
NF++; $NF=sum
```

do:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F, 'NR>1{sum=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; NF++; $NF=sum } 1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked. What if I want to have just the ```Gene``` column and the ```total``` column?

Comment: ? So just print  only them. Remove the `1` on the end and add `print $1, $2` or whatever the column numbers are.

Comment: I get a problem when my gene names start with a number. lets say ```0610005C13Rik``` then in the calculation it adds the ```0610005``` to the final count. Can't we just sum the values from the second column?

Comment: So, obviously, second column has index 2. So instead of `for (i=1` do `for (i=2`

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print $0,"total"
  next
}
{
  for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) 
    $(NF+1)+=$j
  }
  $1=$1
}
1
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** adding solution as per OP's comment to print first column and sum only.

```
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print $0,"total"
  next
}
{
  for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) 
    sum+=$j
  }
  print $1,sum
  sum=""
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Can use perl here:

```sh
perl -MList::Util=sum0 -F, -lane '
    print $_, ",", ($. == 1 ? "total" : sum0( @F[1..$#F] ));
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r row; do
    sum=
    if [[ $row =~ (,[0-9]+)+ ]]; then
        numlist=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        sum=,$((${numlist//,/+}))
    fi
    echo "$row$sum"
done < datafile
```

There are a few assumptions here about rows in the data file: Numeric fields to be summed up are non-negative integers and the first field is not a numeric field (it will not participate in the sum even if it is a numeric field). Also, the numeric fields are consecutive, that is, there is no a non numeric field between two numeric fields. And, the sum won't overflow.